# Third axiom of topology

Tags: general-topology

How can the third axiom of topology (the intersection requirement) be reformulated as:

All neighborhoods $U$ of a point $x\in (X,T)$ contains the closure of a smaller neighborhood $O$ of $x$: $x\in\overline{O}\subset U$.

I have tried to prove this but my attempts have been unsuccessful.

Comment: This is an additional property a space may or may not have. It is equivalent to asking that points and closed sets are separated by open sets, that is, for any $x\in X$ and any closed set $F$ with $x\notin F$, there are open sets $U$ and $V$ with $x\in U$, $F\subset V$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$. Such a space is called **regular**.

Comment: The counter example proposed by Asaf Karagila introduces a topology that doesn't satisfy the third axiom... A closed set and a point don't have distinct neighborhouds

Comment: What do you mean? Is the structure Asaf exhibits not a topology? Or is it a topology, but doesn't satsify the axioms of a topology? It certainly doesn't satisfy the property formulated in the OP - but that was precisely his point

Comment: What you write is called regularity. Not every topology is regular.

Comment: This is a homework problem in a Coursera course. Sanath means "3rd axiom of separation" not "3rd axiom of topology." The 3rd axiom (in this development) is separation of a point and a closed set by disjoint open sets. So, his alternate formulation is equivalent and the question is why?

Comment: @stuart: There is absolutely no way for me to have known that when posting my answer. But it does explain ScaryMango's comment. If the OP will acknowledge this, I'll gladly edit/remove my answer. But until the OP does acknowledge that, I can't, in good conscience edit my answer.

Comment: I'm sorry. I didn't mean to accuse anyone of anything. I wasn't actually aware that MOOC homework questions were a violation to begin with. I was just explaining how I knew what Sananth meant.

Comment: @stuart: Whether or not asking homework questions here is a violation depends on the teacher of that course and the honor code, if one exists, to which the students are bound. I was just explaining (and commenting to Sananth himself) that if it is the case, and my answer is incorrect, then I have no problems with correcting it or removing it altogether; but I'd need him to acknowledge this information, because its **his question**.

Comment: @stuart I did not know that this was a question from Coursera. Me and my friend were discussing topology and he asked me this question. I couldn't answer it and so asked it on math.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can't be formulated like that. Consider the real numbers with the topology generated by the intervals $(-a,a)$ where $a\in\Bbb R$.

Then the closure of every non-empty set is the whole space. Therefore no neighborhood contains the closure of a smaller neighborhood.

Comment: So if there is a neighborhood $U$ of a point $x$, and there is a smaller neighborhood $O$ of $x$, then $O\subset U$?

Comment: What do you mean by smaller?

Comment: With a smaller number of elements.

Comment: You do know that infinite sets can have proper subsets with the same number of elements, right? Also, the answer is not necessarily. Consider the case where $(-1,2)$ and $\Bbb Q$ generate the topology (so you add their union and their intersection). Then $U=(-1,2)$ is an open neighborhood of $0$, $\Bbb Q$ is a smaller neighborhood; but $\Bbb Q\nsubseteq(-1,2)$. And $|\Bbb Q|<|(-1,2)|$.

Comment: I get it. Thanks!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: If there's something wrong with the answer, I'd be happy to correct it.